# How can I make Prism's DelegateCommand observe a child view-model's property?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, delegatecommand

My "parent" view-model (`AnalyzeVm`) has a child view-model (`ScanVm`) that represents something that can be saved to disk.  I want to give the parent a command (`SaveCmd`) that is enabled only when the `ScanVm.IsDirty` property is true.

I already use `DelegateCommand` and its `ObservesProperty` functions all over the place so I tried to use it for this.  But in this one case I cannot get the `ObservesProperty` expression to trigger a call to `CanExecute`.

The difference here (from all the other places I use `ObservesProperty` that work fine) is that I'm monitoring a property of the child object.  Not of my own

I need to understand why this is not working.   I thought this was a valid thing to do.

Here are the two view models (stripped down for clarity)

```
// Parent view-model.  Derives from a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

public class AnalyzeVm : BaseViewModel
{
    private ScanVm _scan;

    public AnalyzeVm(ScanVm scan)
    {
        _scan = scan;

        // Set up the command.  Try to make it monitor a property of the ScanVm
        // object instead of one of our own.

        SaveScanCmd = new DelegateCommand(
            () => { _scan.Save() }                 // execute -- saves the scan
            () => { return _scan.IsDirty; })       // only valid when scan is dirty
            .ObservesProperty(() => scan.IsDirty); // So observe IsDirty property

        // Now just as a sanity check, add a handler for that property changing
        // to the PropertyChangedEventManager and log when it does.

        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(
            scan, 
            (_, _) => Debug.WriteLine("IsDirty changed"), 
            nameof(ScanContext.IsDirty));
    }

    public ICommand SaveScanCmd { get; }

    // other code...
}

// ScanVm class.  

public class ScanVm : BaseViewModel
{
    private bool _isDirty;
    public bool IsDirty
    { 
        get => _isDirty;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isDirty, value);  // Raises PropertyChanged event
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        // Code here to save the ScanVm
       
        IsDirty = false;  // No longer dirty
    }
    // ... other code
}
```

I am sure that the `IsDirty` property is properly changing and firing the event.  I confirmed it many times.  And I'm already using `Observes` property successfully when I observe my own class' properties.  For example,  I were to,  take the `SaveCmd` and move it into the `ScanVm` class itself -- so that the property expression just observed the `ScanVm`'s ***own property***, then it works fine.  I do that all over the place in my code.

This is the only place I'm trying to observe another object's property.  Is it valid to do?  if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservesProperty` primarily works on properties of the containing object

```
public bool IsDirty {...}

...ObservesProperty( () => IsDirty );
```

plus nested properties

```
public ScanVM Child {...}

...ObservesProperty( () => Child.IsDirty );
```

It just doesn't observe properties on any given instance, because it starts looking from the containing object (`AnalyzeVm` in this case).

Comment: Bummer.  I guess I was hoping that it could somehow pick up the instance from the expression.  I'll retool the command.  Thanks

Comment: There _should_ be an error message somewhere like `"scan" is no property of "AnalyzeVm"`, but probably it's just not there.

Comment: I tried and got an exception when observing the property of a field or parameter, actually, not very clear, but clearly not working.

Comment: I don't know why I don't get one, but if it's not what it was designed for, I suppose it's moot.